# Scope error in arduino PinChangeInt library

Tags: arduino

```cpp
#include<PinChangeInt.h>
#define SensorPin 2
int ledPin=10;
int BuzzerPin=12;
volatile byte blip=0;
void blipcount(){
  blip++;
};
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(SensorPin,INPUT);
pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
pinMode(BuzzerPin,OUTPUT);
PCintPort::attachInterrupt(SensorPin,blipCount,FALLING);
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
if(digitalRead(SensorPin)==HIGH){
  digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(BuzzerPin,HIGH);
  Serial.print("blipcoun:\t");
  Serial.println(blip,DEC);
}
if(digitalRead(SensorPin)==LOW){
  digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
  digitalWrite(BuzzerPin,LOW);
}
}
```

I am using arduino uno for a project.I need to record when my sensor gives a high value but i need it to read only falls in pulses.The program is giving  error as

```
Arduino: 1.6.3 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino Uno"

Sense.ino: In function 'void setup()':

Sense.ino:14:38: error: 'blipCount' was not declared in this scope

Error compiling
```

please tell me what is the problem with the function.

The library link is 
https://code.google.com/p/arduino-pinchangeint/downloads/list

tested the code on both 1.72 and 2.19

Comment: `blipcount` is the name of the function, the variable you want is called blip by the looks of it. You are referencing blipCount, which isn't even defined anywhere. Not a lot of information to go on but it'll probably function if you change `PCintPort::attachInterrupt(SensorPin,blipCount,FALLING);` to `PCintPort::attachInterrupt(SensorPin,blip,FALLING);`

Comment: @G_V: tried what you said. Its throwing error that 2nd argument should be userdefined function

Comment: Ah ok, in that case it was probably just the capital letter and `blipcount` should work instead of `blipCount`